# Should I mutate objects within a stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

Say I have a detail model as follows:

```
public class Detail {
    public Integer lineId;
    public Integer quantity;
    public BigDecimal length;
    public Integer sequenceNumber;
}
```

And I have created a list from it.

```
List<Detail> details = details();
```

Now I want to update the sequence number through a method:

```
public void updateSequenceNumbers(List<Detail> details) {
    details.forEach(detail -> detail.sequenceNumber = getNumberFromElsewhere());
}
```

Barring any syntax errors that may have been made above this should work from my understanding. My question is should I do this? I was watching [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/rVfRDLIw_Zw?t=2584) and the presenter specifically mentions that mutating objects outside of streams is a bad idea yet I've seen code like the above many times over. Is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all `details.forEach` is *not* called from `stream`, but directly from `List` - and these are different things. And, of course, you are not mutating *outside* the stream, but the `detail` itself.

Then, you are mutating the inner properties of your object, *not* the `List` itself (`remove` or `add` for example) - this is called a non-structural change and it's more than OK to do this.